# configure nginx to redirect to another server

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi

I have nginx installed on a Raspberry Pi and this works okay.  What I want to do is redirect traffic for a particular port to another server, and have that traffic come back through the Raspberry Pi.  I've got the following in my default sites config;

```
server {
    listen 9001;
    server_name piweb;

    location /transmission {
        proxy_pass http://pyrate:9001/$uri$is_args$args;
        proxy_set_header Host $host:$server_port;
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work obviously.  Is this even possible, or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Answer (score 0):

your configuration seems almost OK, is http://pyrate:9001 accessible from your  pi ? did you try with wget or similar tools ? 
You should remove the $uri$is_args$args - it passes automatically.
Note that it'll search /transmission/[request] on remote server.